# Error: requested entity doesn't exist. When trying to save a query in a project or change visibilty of a query to project visibility

Tags: google-bigquery

Whenever I try to save a query in my project I get the error:

> Requested Entity was not found

There are no issues with saving the query and setting it as public or a private query. I get the same error when I try to change visibility of a public/private query to project visibility.

I do have the preset Editor access to the project.